# save json object in there provided json file using javascript/ node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, nodes

```js
let dataObj={
 print:{
  us:{
  "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   },
   uk:{
    "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"01",
     name:"windows",
     location:"System"
    },
  }
   
 },
 hardware:{
  ja:{
   "9058t05":{
     no:"ct-01",
     refrence:"down-tPO-01"
    }
  }
 }
};


let folderName=[{
  filepath:"print"
 },
 {
  filepath:"hardware"
 },
 {
  filepath:"stack"
 },
 {
  filepath:"backupdir"
 },
];

let cont = {
  "45434dsdfsfv": {
    name: "us",
  },
  "4wer23434": {
    name: "uk",
  },
  "6vfkn23421": {
    name: "ja",
  },
  "9dnfjkn23e": {
    name: "ru",
  },
};


Object.values(cont).map((i) =>{
for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
            for (const [localeKey, localeValues] of Object.entries(values)) {
              console.log(localeValues);
             // fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,key,`${i.name}.json`), JSON.stringify(localeValues, null, 4)
            }
          }
});
```

I am trying to fetch key from the `obj` JSON object and compare it with the Array filepath so I can push the value in created json file

here by using fs I am trying to create folder which I got from the array

```
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,file.filepath,`${cont.name}.json`));
```

by which I created folder and file with the name which are present inside the `cont` json
and trying to put like this

### print/us.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### print/uk.json

```
{
  "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"01",
     name:"windows",
     location:"System"
    },
}
```

### hardware/ja.json

```
{
  "9058t05":{
     no:"ct-01",
     refrence:"down-tPO-01"
    }
}
```

### and so on ...

but the problem is when I do this I am not able to save data in there respective json file
I am getting same output in every json file

### print/us.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### print/uk.json

```
{
   "2343192u4":{
     id:"01",
     name:"linux file",
     location:"System config"
    },
   "23438ufsdjh8":{
     id:"02",
     name:"windows file",
     location:"System config"
   }
 }
```

### and so on ...

here `print hardware stack backupdir` always get changed and there are multiple more files as this is system random generated name that why I have to compare and the key from object and make a directory of this name

how can I push them in different different folder with there respective value

Comment: Check for calls to `getFile` at other code locations.

Comment: reminder: you actually use sync function ```readdirSync``` and ```statSync```and you don't need to use Promise at all.

Comment: @Vikas
, you should keep it simple, also which part of your code is asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

As per you following codebase

```
Object.values(cont).map((i) =>{
for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
            for (const [localeKey, localeValues] of Object.entries(values)) {
              console.log(localeValues);
             // fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,key,`${i.name}.json`), JSON.stringify(localeValues, null, 4)
            }
          }
});
```

You are looping throgh `cont` variable and inside the loop you are iterating over the `dataObj` and `values` object.

The problem is you are not asserting the `i` variable (item of value of `cont` ) with `localKey`. Since you are using `i` variable in the fileName. For all localeKey-localeValue pair, the file name would be same.

So, according to your codebase following would be the flow of execution

```
cont = "us"
    dataObj.hardWare.ja -> write to "/hardware/us.json"
    dataObj.print.uk -> write to "/print/us.json"
    dataObj.print.us -> write to "/print/us.json"
cont = "uk"
    dataObj.hardWare.ja -> write to "/hardware/uk.json"
    dataObj.print.uk -> write to "/print/uk.json"
    dataObj.print.us -> write to "/print/uk.json"
cont = "ja"
    dataObj.hardWare.ja -> write to "/hardware/ja.json"
    dataObj.print.uk -> write to "/print/ja.json"
    dataObj.print.us -> write to "/print/ja.json"
cont = "ru" 
    dataObj.hardWare.ja -> write to "/hardware/ru.json"
    dataObj.print.uk -> write to "/print/ru.json"
    dataObj.print.us -> write to "/print/ru.json"
```

(NOTE: since the object keys are sorted, the `hardware` would processed before `print`. Similarly, `print.uk` would be processed before `print.us`.

Now here, since the `dataObj.print.us` is processed at the end, all the files would have the `dataObj.print.us` data.

**Fix:**
To fix this, you can have something as follow:

```
Object.values(cont).map((i) =>{
    for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
        for (const [localeKey, localeValues] of Object.entries(values)) {
            if (i.name === localeKey) {
                // Create directory
                fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, key), { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });

                // Write data
                fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,key,`${i.name}.json`), JSON.stringify(localeValues, null, 4), (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Full code as follow:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs=require('fs')

let dataObj={
    print:{
        us:{
            "2343192u4":{
                id:"01",
                name:"linux file",
                location:"System config"
            },
            "23438ufsdjh8":{
                id:"02",
                name:"windows file",
                location:"System config"
            },
        },
        uk:{
            "23438ufsdjh8":{
                id:"01",
                name:"windows",
                location:"System"
            },
        }

    },
    hardware:{
        ja:{
            "9058t05":{
                no:"ct-01",
                refrence:"down-tPO-01"
            }
        }
    }
};


let folderName=[{
    filepath:"print"
},
{
    filepath:"hardware"
},
{
    filepath:"stack"
},
{
    filepath:"backupdir"
},
];

let cont = {
    "45434dsdfsfv": {
        name: "us",
    },
    "4wer23434": {
        name: "uk",
    },
    "6vfkn23421": {
        name: "ja",
    },
    "9dnfjkn23e": {
        name: "ru",
    },
};


Object.values(cont).map((i) =>{
    for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
        for (const [localeKey, localeValues] of Object.entries(values)) {
            if (i.name === localeKey) {
                // Create directory
                fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, key), { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });

                // Write data
                fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,key,`${i.name}.json`), JSON.stringify(localeValues, null, 4), (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi @Alok code not working here I am still getting same output

Comment: @Vikas, sorry updated the code now.

Comment: Hi @Alok it still not working even it not writing in the json file

Comment: @vikas, added the whole code for the same. It is working for me.

Comment: yes its working fine and I will award you bounty after 13hr as it showing me you can award bounty after 13hr here